# Security Concerns with TCP Forwarding

Tags: ssh, configuration

Until now I've been setting TCP Forwarding in ssh always blindly to no but searching on the net, I have trouble finding out what the actual security threat is, when allowing it.

The one thing I did find though was that the manpage states, it only helps to turn TCP Forwarding off if users have no shell access. http://joeyh.name/blog/entry/ssh_port_forwarding/ though says, that it's not so important to have no shell access, but `no-port-forwarding` in authorized_keys.

So, - what is the security threat with allowing TCP Forwarding in SSH and will I get rid of that concern when I add `AllowTCPForwarding No` to sshd_config or will I additionally  *have* to restrict the shell access or add the `no-port-forwarding` option?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use an SSH tunnel, as far as the target server is concerned, its client is the SSH server, not the actual client connecting to the SSH tunnel.

For example, if you have an SSH client running on `10.1.1.1`, connecting to an SSH server on `10.2.2.2` and establishing a tunnel to `10.3.3.3`, when a client (possibly from `10.4.4.4` or anywhere else) connects to the tunnel on the `10.1.1.1` end, it gets access to `10.3.3.3` as if it was coming from `10.2.2.2.`, not `10.1.1.1` or `10.4.4.4`.

This allows such connections to bypass firewall rules regarding the target server that would have allowed connections from the machine running the SSH server, but not further.

This is typically a problem if the SSH server is a gateway between two networks, with public IP address and one private IP address, for example. A firewall rule that would only allow access to certain services within the internal LAN wouldn't catch connections from that SSH server (unless a special case was made for that machine).

The remote connections may come from much further. On the SSH client side, some SSH clients can bind their listening socket to a specific IP address (e.g. `localhost`), at least to prevent connections from remote machines from that end. However, you rely on the client using these settings properly.

If your users are allowed to make this sort of connections, or if the firewall (and related) rules you use on your network handle the SSH server's IP address specifically to take this into account this, it can be fine. This being said, you may still want to check where the tunnels are established too, you could also get into trouble with other third party servers too otherwise.

If you don't need any of this, disabling this feature would be better.

Answer (score 7):

TCP forwarding allows users to use SSH to set up a VPN which they can use to tunnel into a network. This could allow an attacker to circumvent network security measures like firewalls. SSH tunneling can be an extremely useful tool, but it is also a security risk, so it should be disabled unless it is explicitly required.